# Can't subtract float value from float in for loop?

Tags: c, floating-point, subtraction

I started learning C for first day and wanted to create program that asks user how much change is owed and then say out minimum number of coins with which change can be made. Assuming that the only coins are quarters(0.25), dimes(0.10), nickels(0.05) and pennies(0.01). So if the change owed would be 1.15 so then this program should say 4 quarters, 1 dime and 1 nickel. Anyways.

Problem is that i tried to subtract 0.25 from float change when change value is 0.25 or more.

```
int main(void)
{
    float change;
    printf("Kui palju on vaja peenraha tagasi maksta?\n");
    change = GetFloat();

    float quarters;
    for (change; change >= 0.25; change - 0.25, quarters++) // This is where i tried to subtract. Look only on this line because everything else is incomplete.
    {
        printf("change= %f and quarters= %f", change, quarters);
    }


}
```

And this is the output i got, this program will keep doing so on and on.
[image]

This is so weird because change-- works but change - 0.25 doesn't. Did i do something wrong? Are there alternatives that work?

Comment: Floating point arithmetics on computers will always lead to rounding errors, so while it's okay to use for beginners exercises remember that for real applications you should never use floating point types for money.

Comment: Posting text as _text_ rather than as a _picture_ of text is a courteous and more useful way to present data.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg You are right. It wont recognize 0.01 as pennie. But with bigger numbers it does. Weird. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change:

```
for (change; change >= 0.25; change - 0.25, quarters++)
```

to:

```
for (change; change >= 0.25; change = change - 0.25, quarters++)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize quarters (and why is quarters a float? Can you have 1.7 quarters?). And perhaps this is more readable:

```
int quarters = 0;
while ( change >= .25 ) {
   quarters++;
   change -= .25;
}
```